# UTF-8 server side conversion from euc-kr in Korean loses about 15% of characters

Tags: android, utf-8, base64

During conversion to UTF8 at the server, some of the Korean is not converting correctly(like 15% of the characters).

From server we are getting characters in euc-kr format.

**Current scenario:**

```
public static String decodeString(String encoded) {
        if (encoded == null) {
            encoded = "";
        } else if (encoded.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            encoded = "";
        } else if (encoded.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            encoded = "true";
        } else if (encoded.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            encoded = "false";
        } else {
            encoded = new String(Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT));

        }
        return encoded;
    }
```

**Server: EUCKR Korean data -> convert to UTF8 -> base64 encode -> send to client**

At our Side:

**Client: receive base64encoded content -> decode base 64 -> displaying UTF8**

However, during the conversion to UTF8 at the server, some of the Korean is not converting correctly(like 15% of the characters).

For example, for the text 에디 쵝오

when doing euckr -> base64 encoding

but when doing euckr -> utf8 -> base64, : (this cuts the string in the middle)

Wanted to see if the app can handle displaying euckr format directly.

Comment: Can you post the conversion code you are using? And unless the conversion happens on the phone, don't tag this Android, tag according to your server-side technology.

Comment: Ok fine,In Android can i decoding the following base64 code without using Utf-8 and display it in korean on the android & iphone?

v6G18Kyev8Ah

Comment: public static String decodeString(String encoded) {
  if (encoded == null) {
   encoded = "";
  } else if (encoded.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
   encoded = "";
  } else if (encoded.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
   encoded = "true";
  } else if (encoded.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
   encoded = "false";
  } else {
   encoded = new String(Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT));

  }
  return encoded;
 }

Comment: you have to pass the data with webservices using XML or JSON parsing..
have you idea about that ..If you want to do this with android .

Comment: ... Why are you base64-encoding if you're using JSON?

Comment: sir it is coming from server.. and at my side in android i have to solve this problem.

Comment: If you use JSON, why bother with Base64 encoding? UTF-8 data in JSON works fine.

Comment: If what the server sends is already broken, you cannot fix it client-side.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i discussed this problem with them. they are ready to change data at server side. what should i suggest them so that it works fine on both android and iPhone.